# Filter values from a combination of more than one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Click here for link to workbook (Google Drive) as image not clear](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QJCdR2o8I5fB_aqHh339JOiJ2o7tjBet/view?usp=sharing)

Admittedly, I am quite an amateur when using excel aggregate function.

From attached image, please, how will I be able to filter names from both column B and E such that every entry with destination will be recorded accordingly on columns K:O as shown

I have tried using the following formula which only returns values from Manual entry table (columns E:F) but it doesn't take values on column B from the Automatic table (columns A:C). For instance when I recorded "BEN" as having gone to LAGOS on column B, it returned "0" on column O instead of "BEN"

=IFERROR(INDEX($E:$E,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$3:$B$50:$E$3:$E$20)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C$3:$C$50:$F$3:$F$20,{"LAGOS"},0))),ROW($ZZ1))),"")

[image: File Screenshot]

Comment: Unable to see the screen shot since has small view better share the WB if  possible !

Comment: @RajeshS currently struggling to attach WB. Will update in due time

Comment: @RajeshS I haven't been able to figure how to attach file. Is it possible to share your email and I'll send attachment?

Comment: Here you can share link of Google Drive/Drop Box or any suitable medium otherwise just find my mail Id with my profile ☺

Comment: Your picture is not clearly to determine the problem, try to provide the more clearly picture here.

Comment: @Lee Please check edited question. Google drive file added. Thank you

Comment: @RajeshS Please check edited question. Google drive file added. Thank you

Comment: @TeodrosIV,,, thanks give me some time ,, will back to post soon ☺

Comment: @RajeshS no worries, thank you 

Comment: Instead of aggregating, why not have only one table, if it is automatic, then have a scan id or if it is manual the scan id = manual. Then a pivot table or `FILTER()` could solve your problem...

Comment: @TeodrosIV ,,, now check my post ,,, I do believe that it's exactly what U were looking for, plzz confirm through comments & if it works then you may accept it as an answer as well up vote ☺

Answer (score -1):

*This solves the issue:*

---

[image]

---

- An array (CSE) formula in cell A67:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($H$67:$H$74, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A$66, $I$67:$I$74), ROW($G$67:$I$74)-MIN(ROW($G$67:$I$74))+1), ROW($A1)), COLUMN($A1)),"")}
  ```

---

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill across.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.